# How can I link several domains to one Laravel project?

Tags: laravel, laravel-valet, dynamic-url, valet

I have this one project, that has 3 databases and 1 dynamic page, which takes content from those databases. I need 3 different URLs (url1.test, url2.test, url3.test), each should contain one page, filled with data from assigned database. How can I do that?
I tried valet, but can "park" only the whole project.

Here is the code of my controller function.

````
    public function instance ($dbname) {
        $json = DB::connection($dbname)->select('select json from config')[0]->json;
        $config = json_decode($json, true);
        if ($config['status'] == 'enabled')
            return view('instance', ['config'=>$config]);
        else
            return view('blocked');
    }```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `park` command is used to tell Valet where to look at to find projects. In your case, you want to link a different domain to your project.

What you need to do is go inside your project folder and run `valet link url2`. This way, `url2.test` will be linked to your app.

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/valet#the-link-command